# Is it possible to share a library import module I have created across several modules?

Tags: python, module

I have several modules, all stored in the same directory. Each requires a lengthy list of libraries (numpy, pandas, etc.).

I have created one module called library_function in which I have defined the following function:

```
def library_fun():
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    print("test)
    #etc. many more libraries
```

In my main module, I have the following code:

```
# import required modules
from library_function import library_fun

# bring in the required libraries; see separate module for this
library_fun()

# Bring in Production Data
production_data = pd.Series([1,2])
```

I get an error "name 'pd' is not defined".

I know that library_fun is running - I can see the "test" printout.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: From `import this`, otherwise known as the Zen of Python: explicit is better than implicit. Just use the copy/paste function and import the libraries where needed.

Comment: Also, your example won't work because pandas and numpy are being imported into the function's namespace, not the global one.